# Physical interpretation of superposition state

Tags: quantum-state, experimental-realization, hardware

I was confused with interpreting superposition state in the anharmonic energy diagram. In the anharmonic energy diagram, an energy pulse can shift the state of the qubit from $|0\rangle$ to $|1\rangle$, so how can I interpret the action of microwave pulses as a result of a Hadamard gate? Can the qubit exist between these two states when interpreting through energy diagram?